# Parents UK Visitor Visa Refused - please help!

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I have recently applied for a UK Vusitor Visa for my parents who live in India and it got rejected. My parents are retired and I was going to sponsor their whole trip to UK for 3 months which I have mentioned clearly on the Invitation letter and Sponsorship letter stating my Salary, payslips and UK bank statements from my side. As for my parents' financial proof, I have added their bank statements with balance around £4.4k and a letter by Chartered Accountant, stating the property, fixed deposit and assets worth £33K ( which I think got completely neglected by the ECO). I have got the rejection with below points:

******************** Letter *****************

> **The decision**
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not
>   satisfied that you meet requirements of paragraph 4 2 of Appendix V
>   Immigration Rules for Visitors because:-
>
> 1.You have applied to travel to the UK alongside your wife for three months to visit your son i have taken into account that you have
>   provided details of your sponsor's financial and living circumstances
>   in the United Kingdom and l am very aware of the importance of family
>   visits and the significance which should be afforded to maintaining
>   family links, however, it is your circumstances as the applicant which
>   is of most importance.
>
> 2.You have stated on your application form that you and your wife are both retired. You have not stated in your application form or
>   presented documentation to suggest that you are in receipt of any
>   regular income. You have estimated the personal cost of this visit at
>   £2,000 To demonstrate your financial circumstances you have provided
>   an Indian Bank statement, account ending ******5190, which shows a
>   closing balance of Rs.360,450 (£4,291). You therefore propose to spend
>   over half of your savings on this visit to the UK. Given your
>   financial circumstances as outlined above, and that you have not
>   demonstrated any income, I am not satisfied that this proposed
>   expenditure is credible.
>
> 3.I have also considered the pattern of deposits into your bank account. I note that in the month of February 2017, this account
>   received a number of deposits totalling Rs.200,190 (£2,383). I am
>   unable to confirm from the documents submitted the origin of these
>   funds.
>
> 4.In light of all of the above I am not satisfied as to your intentions in wishing to travel to the United Kingdom or that you will
>   leave the UK at the end of your visit. Furthermore, I am not satisfied
>   that you have sufficient funds available to cover your costs whilst in
>   the UK without working or accessing public funds Your application for
>   a visit visa has been refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) (e)

I am considering reapplying for the Visa, but I wanted to clarify below doubts? So, can you please guide me on the below points based on their experience?

Questions  : 
For point 2: 
a. As my parents are retired they dont have a regular income - how should I respond to this question?
b. For spending half of the amount - We can dissolve one of the properties worth 15 lakh and provide the proof of same - will that work?

For Point 3 : Also, I keep on sending money to them, is it fine to state that in my next application?

Thanks in Advance
Sunny

Comment: contrast and compare to https://www.immigrationboards.com/general-uk-immigration-forum/visitor-visa-rejected-t230109.html